# How to set width to 100%

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, styling

I have a silverlight stackpanel and i want to set its width to 100%.

i'm adding the stackpanel dynamically (C#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting HorizontalAlignment to "Stretch" on your StackPanel and make sure your containing element is also the width you expect.

Comment: "Stretch" is the default value anyway so there shouldn't be a need to set it all.  You're correct though, its probably the containing element that Gaby really needs to be looking at.

Comment: True, I'm just thinking that maybe he's got some style defined somewhere else that un-sets it...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateMyDynamicStackPanel()
{
    StackPanel MyStackPanel = new StackPanel();
    MyStackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    MyStackPanel.Width = 300;
}
```

Instead of 300, use a property of the parent container?

Comment: I'm loading all the page dynamically and the stackpanel is added on the constructor of the page, so the parent width will be N\A and the actualWidth is equal zero.